# Scraping images from Website in delphi with twebbrowser

Tags: image, delphi, twebbrowser

im trying to make a small tool which downloads all images from the site visited. It have to be made with twebbrowser component. The test site from my customer is [Click](http://frisurenmachen.de). At the moment im selecting the pictures with getelementbyid but some of the pictures dont have a id. How can i adress the missing ones? Thanks alot

Comment: Work through the dom looking for images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the page is loaded, query the `TWebBrowser.Document` property for the [`IHTMLDocument2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574.aspx) interface, and then you can enumerate the elements of the [`IHTMLDocument2.images`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752593.aspx) collection:

```
var
  Document: IHTMLDocument2;
  Images: IHTMLElementCollection;
  Image: IHTMLImgElement;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Document := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  Images := Document.images;
  For I := 0 to Images.length - 1 do
  begin
    Image := Images.item(I, '') as IHTMLImgElement;
    // use Image as needed...
  end;
end;
```

Note that this will only find images in HTML `<img>` tags.  If you need to find images in `<input type="image">` tags as well, you will have to enumerate the elements of the [`IHTMLDocument2.all`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752582.aspx) collection looking for instances of the [`IHTMLInputElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703817.aspx) interface whose [`type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703833.aspx) property is `"image"`, eg:

```
var
  Document: IHTMLDocument2;
  Elements: IHTMLElementCollection;
  Element: IHTMLElement;
  Image: IHTMLImgElement;
  Input: IHTMLInputElement;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Document := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  Elements := Document.all;
  For I := 0 to Elements.length - 1 do
  begin
    Element := Elements.item(I, '') as IHTMLElement;
    if Element is IHTMLImgElement then begin
      Image := Element as IHTMLImgElement;
      // use Image as needed...
    end
    else if Element is IHTMLInputElement then begin
      Input := Element as IHTMLInputElement;
      if Input.type = 'image' then
      begin
        // use Input as needed...
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of requesting a specific element by id, you can "walk" the document and look at each element using WebDocument.all.item(itemnum,'').

```
var
  cAllElements: IHTMLElementCollection;
  eThisElement: IHTMLElement;
  WebDocument: IHTMLDocument2;
```

=======

```
 cAllElements:=WebDocument.All
  For iThisElement:=0 to cAllElements.num-1 do
    begin
      eThisElement:=cAllElements.item(iThisElement,'') as IHTMLElement;
      // check out eThisElement and do what you want
    end;
```

You would then look at the element .tagName for IMG, or do whatever assessment you need in order to determine if it is a picture and handle it as you did before.

Dan

Comment: Walking the document's `images` collection would be more straight-forward than walking the `all` collection.

Comment: I agree.  I had forgot about the images collection.  Either would work, but using the images collection would be more straightforward.  The .all collection is more useful for ad-hoc searches.